# Trouble to build a SQL join

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I want to check if the values of the 3 fields of the table "T2" appear together for each user in the table "T1", something joined like this:

[image: ![Tentative of illustration]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaM3i.png)

Expected outcome:

[image]

Is this possible at all? If yes, can you please help to build a query for it?

Thank you

[Link to the MS access file:](https://mega.nz/#!w7BmRATK!sUxOhmwZoJdvHxnY7ydDBsyh0xSPlJbtOc-Hw8U-jHY)

Comment: Is there a User field in T1?

Comment: No, each record in T1 represent a combination of different system privileges which should not be granted together to the same user. So in T2 I have all the users and all their privileges, and I am trying to identify who has *forbidden* combinations.

Comment: How do the rows differ in T1? Is there some other field indicator not shown?

Comment: You will get more help if you start a query and post it for help getting it to work.  I am not sure about msaccess syntax but in TSQL I would consider a pivot of T1 and join on the R field.  Then do a count of that result grouped by user and where the count = max count of T1 (in this case 3) those are the 'forbidden' records you are looking for.

Comment: @Parfait, T1 (right side of the image) will have a unique combination of 3 different accesses represented by numeric codes, so if we take the first row as an example the combination of the access 0001 + 0002 + 0003 is not supposed to happen. Then in T2 (left side of the image) it happens that "User 1* has 3 accesses and they happen to be exactly the same of the first record in T1. I thought of something like this:  SELECT *
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON (T1.R3 = T2.R) AND (T1.R2 = T2.R) AND (T1.R1 = T2.R);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions based on posted example: Only 3 factors and factors can be in any field of T1.

Need a unique identifier field in each table, an autonumber should serve.

query: T1_UNION (A UNION query must be typed (or copy/paste) in SQLView of query builder.)
`SELECT RecID_T1, "R1" AS Cat, R1 AS Data FROM T1
UNION SELECT RecID_T1, "R2", R2 FROM T1
UNION SELECT RecID_T1, "R3", R3 FROM T1;`

query: T2_CROSSTAB
`TRANSFORM First(T2.R) AS FirstOfR
SELECT T2.U
FROM T2
GROUP BY T2.U
PIVOT DCount("*","T2","U='" & [U] & "' AND RecID_T2<" & [RecID_T2])+1;`

query:
`SELECT T2_CROSSTAB.U, DLookUp("Data","T1_UNION","Data='" & [1] & "'") AS IsMatch1, DLookUp("Data","T1_UNION","Data='" & [2] & "'") AS IsMatch2, DLookUp("Data","T1_UNION","Data='" & [3] & "'") AS IsMatch3
FROM T2_CROSSTAB
WHERE ((Not (DLookUp("Data","T1_UNION","Data='" & [1] & "'")) Is Null) AND (Not (DLookUp("Data","T1_UNION","Data='" & [2] & "'")) Is Null) AND (Not (DLookUp("Data","T1_UNION","Data='" & [3] & "'")) Is Null));`

Using Joe C's idea, CROSSTAB is not needed.

query: Data_GROUPED
`SELECT T2.U, T2.R
FROM T2 INNER JOIN T1_UNION ON T2.R = T1_UNION.Data
GROUP BY T2.U, T2.R
ORDER BY T2.U;`

query:
`SELECT Data_GROUPED.U, Count(Data_GROUPED.R) AS CountOfR
FROM Data_GROUPED
GROUP BY Data_GROUPED.U
HAVING (((Count(Data_GROUPED.R))=3));`

Comment: Thanks, but MS Access does not seem to support these operations. I have edited the topic with the link to the file or another screenshot of the expected outcome.

Comment: I built tables and queries in MS Access - all works. A UNION query must be typed (or copy/paste) in SQLView of query builder. See my edited answer, changed to require unique ID for both approaches.

Comment: Amazing!! I can finish form there, thank you very much!!